# Time-independent wave function in a 3D square box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

> An electron is confined in a three-dimensional infinite potential
>   well. The sides parallel to the $x-$, $y-$, and $z-\text {axes}$ are
>   of length $L$ each.

How do we write the time-independent wave function corresponding to the state
of the lowest possible energy?

I just know the wave function of the lowest energy level is

$$\psi_{111} = (x,y,z) = \psi_1(x)\psi_1(y)\psi_1(z)$$

Comment: I hope I asked it well.

Comment: It is answered in this Wiki article: [Particle in a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box)

Comment: @lemon I had seen that. However, didn't get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated separation of variables will show the solution is of the from $\phi(x,y,z)=\psi_{n_x}(x)\psi_{n_y}(y)\psi_{n_z}(z)$ as you are given.  It is then a simple matter to apply
$H=H_x+H_y+H_z$ on this type of solution to find the total energy, remembering that, for instance,
$$
H_x\psi_{n_x}(x)\psi_{n_y}(y)\psi_{n_z}(z)
$$
only “sees the $x$-part” of the product since the $y$- and $z$-functions are unaffected by
$$
H_x=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V(x)\, .
$$